# How to make a F# discriminated union out of another type's union cases?

Tags: f#

Imagine this discriminated union:

```
type Direction = 
    | North
    | South
    | East
    | West
```

Now imagine that I want a type which only accepts tuples of (North, South) or (East, West).  Perhaps this will describe train routes which only run North to South, or East to West.  (North, East) and (South, West) should be forbidden, perhaps because the trains don't run like that.

This doesn't work:

```
type TrainLines = 
    | North, South
    | East, West
```

Even though that doesn't work, perhaps you can see what I'm trying to do.

This works, but doesn't restrict possibilites to only (North, South) and (East, West):

```
type TrainLines = Direction * Direction
```

Any guidance would be welcomed.

Answer (score 10):

This isn't exactly what you asked for, but I think it's likely that

```
type TrainLines =
    | NorthSouth
    | EastWest
```

would do you good.  If needed you could add e.g.

```
    with member this.Directions =
           match this with
           | NorthSouth -> [North; South]
           | EastWest -> [East; West]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do exactly what you want, because `North`, `South`, `East` and `West` aren't types of their own. So you can't have something like `North * South`; and `North, South` is a value of type `Direction * Direction`, but not the only one. Just like you can't define the type

```
type Digit = 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9
```

Answer (score 2):

> Now imagine that I want a type which
>   only accepts tuples of (North, South)
>   or (East, West).

Interesting feature request: sounds like you want "static range constraints", e.g.

```
//fictional syntax for static range constraints
type TrainLine = (a,b) where (a=North and b=South) or (a=East and b=West)

let northSouth = TrainLine(North,South) // compiles
let northEast = TrainLine(North,East) // does not compile
```

Such a feature seems plausible in a language with only literals, but where we get into trouble is when we consider values only known at runtime:

```
let parseDirection userInputString = 
    match userInputString with
    | "North" -> North
    | "South" -> South
    | "East" -> East
    | "West" -> West
    | _ -> failwith "invalid direction"

let directionA = parseDirection(System.Console.ReadLine())
let directionB = parseDirection(System.Console.ReadLine())

//compiler can't enforce constraint because direction values unknown until runtime
let trainLine = TrainLine(directionA,directionB)
```

However, F#'s does have a nice set of features in Active Patterns which can help to convert runtime input into a set of known cases and then proceed with static confidence:

```
let (|NorthSouth|EastWest|Invalid|) (a,b) = 
    match a,b with
    | North,South -> NorthSouth
    | East,West -> EastWest
    | _ -> Invalid

let trainLines = [(North,South); (South,North); (East,West); (North,East);(North,North); (South,East)]

let isValidTrainLine trainLine = 
    match trainLine with
    | NorthSouth -> true
    | EastWest -> true
    | Invalid -> false

let validTrainLines = trainLines |> List.filter isValidTrainLine
//val it : (Direction * Direction) list = [(North, South); (East, West)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You really want polymorphic variants from OCaml:

```
[ `North | `South | `East | `West ]
[ `North | `South ] * [ `East | `West ]
```

but F# is currently incapable of expressing this. I actually find I need this a lot in my work...

You can introduce unnecessary layers of union types:

```
type ns = North | South
type ew = East | West
type nsew = NorthSouth of ns | EastWest of ew
```

and then use `ns * ew`.

Another solution that can sometimes work well is to use an interface to provide a consistency between two separate union types:

```
type IDir = abstract AsInt : int
type ns =
  | North
  | South
  interface IDir with
    method d.AsInt =
      match d with North -> 0 | South -> 1
type ew =
  | East
  | West
  interface IDir with
    method d.AsInt =
      match d with East -> 2 | West -> 3
```

Sadly, this imposes all of the disadvantages of OOP...